# Web Scraping In Python Selenium: Why is my code not grabbing the price element?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have this program that is scraping a page on lowes. It seems to working properly with grabbing the product model number and description. however, it will not grab the price. I have tried locating by Class name, CSS Selector, and XPATH and none seem to work. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

def scrape_page_data():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')))
    container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')

    # scroll down to load all content on the page
    for _ in range(4):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
        time.sleep(2)

    skus = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tooltip-custom')
    prices = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.price-section span.price-regular')
    description = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.titl-cnt.titl.brnd-desc')

    return skus, prices, description

def pagination(url, pages=1):
    prod_num = []
    prod_price = []
    prod_desc = []

    page_num = 0
    # iterate over the pages
    for i in range(1, pages+1):

        #print(f"this is page {i}")
        driver.get(f"{url}?Nao={page_num}")
        skus, prices, description = scrape_page_data()

        for sku in skus:
            prod_num.append(sku.text)
        for price in prices:
            prod_price.append(price.text)
        for desc in description:
            prod_desc.append(desc.text)
        print(f"prod_num: {prod_num}")
        print(f"prod_price: {prod_price}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {prod_desc}")
        print(f"prod_num: {len(prod_num)}")
        print(f"prod_price: {len(prod_price)}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {len(prod_desc)}")



        # increment it by 24 since each page has 24 data
        page_num += 24
        time.sleep(1)

    return prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc

website = 'https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-panels-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858283'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc = pagination(website, pages=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price, 'brand': prod_desc})
df.to_csv('dw_tools9.csv', index=False)
print(df)

driver.quit()
```

I would like this program to be able to grab the price as it is the most important part.I have a check in my code to look at the length of the arrays and the price array is at 0 meaning that the program is not scraping that element at all. Here is the link to the website: https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-panels-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858283

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locator for the prices is

```
div.prdt-actl-pr
```

---

Also in your `scrape_page_data()` method,

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')))
container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')
```

1. You are waiting for `*_all_elements` but only need one. Switch that to `.presence_of_element_located()`.
2. These two lines can be combined because the wait returns the element.

   ```
   container = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')))
   ```

---

You can scroll to the bottom of the page using

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```